# If I have a Linear mixed effects model (lmer) that allows for the Intercept to vary among g1 and g2 within g1. Can g2 also be a fixed effect?

Tags: regression, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, random-effects-model

I am using the lme4 package with R and would like to allow the intercept to vary with my fixed effects to allow for a proper fit, so basically I assume my random effects would follow this:

(1 | g1/g2) with the alternative  (1 | g1)+(1 | g1:g2)

In my case my full model would be:

```
lmer(signal ~ 1 + g2 + g3 + (1|g1) + (1|g1:g2) + (1|g1:g3),
     data = dat, REML = FALSE)
```

But as you may have noticed, the variables (categorical factors g2 and g3) that I want to allow the intercept to vary for are also my fixed effects. I have not seen this in an example before and wanted to know: is it valid to do this if g2 and in my case also g3 are also fixed effects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Fixed vs Random

In this context, an effect is fixed *or* random. Random effects can affect fixed effects, but one explanatory variable cannot be both fixed and random.

### Specifying Fixed Effects Affected by Random Effects

`(1 | g1 / g2)` implies `g2` is a random effect nested in `g1` (e.g. `(1 | school / class)`). It also implies you are estimating a random *intercept*.

> I want to allow the intercept to vary for are also my fixed effects

If you suspect the fixed effects are affected by the random effect, you should include a random *slope*, even for categorical variables. This may seem a little confusing, but consider the slope for your categorical variable additions to the intercept. In that case, you could model `(g2 | g1)` or if you believe both are affected `(g2 + g3 | g1)`

`lme4` automatically estimates the fixed effects correctly if the random effects are correctly specified, respecting the hierarchy of the data.

If I understand your question correctly, the model would then look something like this:

```
lmer(signal ~ g2 + g3 + (g2 + g3|g1), data = dat)
```

You don't have to include `1 + ...` in the fixed part, because an intercept is estimated by default.

Note: Unless you are comparing models, it might be better to leave REML on, because ML can be biased for the random effects, especially if the data are unbalanced.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Just to give you more information, I am looking at neural responses (signal) in eyes. g2 is contrast and g3 is intensity of the light stimulus. In order for the model to fit correctly I have to allow for variation at different values of contrast and intensity within different animals (g1). I believe you have answered my question, as it seems that the fixed effects (g2 and g3) are affected by the random effect g1. With that information, would you agree?

Comment: hmm it seems I am now met with quite a few error codes:             
Warning messages:
1: In commonArgs(par, fn, control, environment()) :
  maxfun < 10 * length(par)^2 is not recommended.
2: In optwrap(optimizer, devfun, getStart(start, rho$lower, rho$pp),  :
  convergence code 1 from bobyqa: bobyqa -- maximum number of function evaluations exceeded
3: In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
  Model failed to converge with max|grad| = 0.079353 (tol = 0.002, component 1). Do you have any idea of how I could get around this?

Comment: @Jakey, those are convergence warnings. You might want to consult this page: https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/33653_57fc7b8e5d484c909b615d8633c01d51.html